# Not deleting the line with "0"

Tags: c#, string, text, text-files

I have wrote a function in my C# application, which should delete the entire line when ever **"0"** is coming.
But i don't know my output text file is not deleting this.

How can i tackle this situation.

Code snippet:

```
   public void do_name()
    {
        string[] search_text = new string[] { "PCB", "DOC", "PCB1", "DOC1" };
        string old;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(textBox1.Text))
        {
            while ((old = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (old.Contains(search_text[0]) || old.Contains(search_text[1]) ||
                    old.Contains(search_text[2]) || old.Contains(search_text[3]) ||
                   old.Split(" ".ToArray()).Equals("0"))
                     //here delete's the line where, "PCB", "DOC", "PCB1", "DOC1" is coming.
                     //but not '0"
                    continue;
                else
                    sb.AppendLine(old);
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
        File.WriteAllText(textBox1.Text, sb.ToString());
    }
```

My input text file looks like below:

```
       "CN5"    "210-0141"  "PHOENIX/8/150/V/F" "353.441"   "115.951"
       "CN8"    "210-0141"  "PHOENIX/8/150/V/F" "317.881"   "115.824"
       "CN9"    "210-0141"  "PHOENIX/8/150/V/F" "265.176"   "115.951"
        "*1"    "210-0150"  ""  "0" "0"
        "*10"   "210-0150"  ""  "0" "0"
        "*11"   "210-0150"  ""  "0" "0"
        "*12"   "210-0150"  ""  "0" "0"
        "*13"   "210-0150"  ""  "0" "0"
        "*14"   "210-0150"  ""  "0" "0"
        "*15"   "210-0150"  ""  "0" "0"
```

Comment: What do you mean by `"0" is coming.` anyway ?

Comment: there is a difference between `==` and `.Equals` Stacy one compares Objects while the other one compares values in simplified terms

Comment: @FlorianF. in my input text file.. there will be "0" like this/// so i need to delete this entire line. when ever  "0" comes!!

Comment: use the debugger.. and step thru the code..  also you do not need to new up the string[] since you are initializing it already with values so this will also work the same `string[] search_text = { "PCB", "DOC", "PCB1", "DOC1" };`

Comment: why not check ahead then `if(old[3] == 0.ToString() || old[4] == 0.ToString(){ continue;}` your logic looks backwards .. what do these have to do with the input file `"PCB", "DOC", "PCB1", "DOC1"`

Comment: @DJKRAZE"0" as one of the split values

Comment: you are wanting to split the file based on spaces correct.. you do not want to split on "0" "0" is a value not a delimiter

Comment: Unlike Java, in C#, you should rarely use `Equals`. It hides type problems.

Comment: I can split that file out and get it to work with very few lines of code.. If the input file is coming in and you are to capture all lines that do not have the value "0" then 0 is not a delimiter to split on..

Comment: @DJKRAZE OK LET me brief it.. i need to delete the enitre line.. when ever '0" is coming. right now.. it is taking all the lines.. and deleteing becaise all my lines have 0.. so i dont want to do that.. i just need to look for **double qoutes 0 double qoutes**

Comment: @DJKRAZE any idea!! please see my input file http://pastie.org/9719270

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
old.Split(" ".ToArray()).Equals("0"))
```

Will *always* be false because `Split` returns an *array* and you're compoaring it to a *String*.

I suspect you want

```
old == "0"
```

instead.  Either that or you need to be clear on your condition (A `0` *anywhere* in the string? A `0` as one of the split values`?  A "0" as the *first* split value?)

> as one of the split values

then use

```
old.Split('\t').Contains(@"""0"""))
```

Note that the overload for `Split` that takes a character array uses the `params` keyword, so you can pass in a single character rather than converting a string to a character array.  I also included the `0` in quotes since that's how your input data is formatted.

Comment: Or `old.StartsWith("0")` or `old.Contains("0")`, it pretty much depends on what "0 is coming" means.

Comment: @D Stanley still its coming

Comment: @D Stanley please see my input file..

Comment: @D Stanley  as one of the split values

Comment: @D Stanley still the output is coming with 0 :-(

Comment: @D Stanley  please see my input file here.. ..copy every thing to a notepad.. its the same format.. http://pastie.org/9719270

Comment: Your input is _tab_ delimited, not _space_ delimited.  I have updated my answer to reflect that.  I would update your question with these details to get it re-opened if my answer still doesn't work.

Comment: @DStanley PERFECT .. I FORGOT TO MENTION MY TEXTFILE WAS TAB DELIMITED/.. SORRY ABOUT THAT.. IT WORKED PERFECTLY..

Comment: @DStanley also please tell me suppose if i have a text like this.. http://pastie.org/9719315 how can i delete the last column.. i mean.. i want to delete the enitre column. LAYER from it.. how can i do this.. please let me know.. thanks a lot

Comment: Read it line by line, change the string, save it to a new file line by line.  Sounds like a good follow-up question.